# CNAME to local domain does not resolve

Tags: linux, networking, dns, docker, fritzbox

I have a server on my LAN wich I want to access with a public domain name, but it should be reachable only within my local network.

To do that, I added a CNAME record on my domain (`example.org`) to point `myserver.example.org` to `myserver.fritz.box`.

On my host machine this works flawlessly, but inside a docker container running on the host I can't resolve the CNAME.

Resolving on my host:

```
host# dig myserver.example.org 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> myserver.example.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49974
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.example.org.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.example.org.   0   IN  CNAME   myserver.fritz.box.
myserver.fritz.box. 9   IN  A   192.168.178.155

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sa Jul 01 16:54:58 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

Resolving inside the container. I tried a blank ubuntu and debian base image and in both I only receive a `NXDOMAIN` response:

```
container# dig myserver.example.org 

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16 <<>> myserver.example.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 177
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.example.org.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.example.org.   0   IN  CNAME   myserver.fritz.box.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
box.            1823    IN  SOA ns0.centralnic.net. hostmaster.centralnic.net. 1688220651 900 1800 6048000 3600

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 01 14:57:46 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149
```

That also leads to me being unable to ping the server from inside the container:

```
container# ping myserver.example.org
ping: bad address 'myserver.example.org'
```

Note that manually doing another query for the local domain name works fine also inside the container.

```
container# dig myserver.fritz.box

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16 <<>> myserver.fritz.box
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2636
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.fritz.box.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.fritz.box. 9   IN  A   192.168.178.155

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
myserver.fritz.box. 9   IN  NS  fritz.box.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
fritz.box.      9   IN  A   192.168.178.1
fritz.box.      9   IN  AAAA    fd00::cece:1eff:fef4:c4db
fritz.box.      9   IN  AAAA    2a01:c22:d145:6900:cece:1eff:fef4:c4db

;; Query time: 252 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 01 14:58:27 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 158
```

Why do we have this discrepancy?

Shouldn't docker's DNS server `127.0.0.11` simply forward the request to `127.0.0.53` on the host machine, where everything works fine?

---

#### Maybe related

I've noticed the same issue also on my host machine, if I'm explicitly using the DNS server of my router, instead of `127.0.0.53` from resolvectl. I don't understand why this is happening either.

```
host# dig @fritz.box myserver.example.org 

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @fritz.box myserver.example.org
; (3 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 13570
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;myserver.example.org.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
myserver.example.org.   0   IN  CNAME   myserver.fritz.box.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
box.            1641    IN  SOA ns0.centralnic.net. hostmaster.centralnic.net. 1688220651 900 1800 6048000 3600

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 2a01:c22:d145:6900:cece:1eff:fef4:c4db#53(2a01:c22:d145:6900:cece:1eff:fef4:c4db)
;; WHEN: Sa Jul 01 17:00:48 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 149
```

Comment: What are the time to live values in your zone file?

Comment: @xenoson 300 is the TTL for the new records I've created. I just checked (~24 hours) after the changes to the DNS records and the problem is still as described above.

Comment: can your docker even resolve the local host normally? or does it have a different DNS that overrides this myserver.fritz.box with something else?

Comment: @LPChip, `ping myserver.fritz.box` works fine from inside the docker container.

Comment: Can your docker reach the internet though? I mean, at all?

Comment: @LPChip, Yes, I can resolve/reach servers on the internet just fine. And I can resolve/reach servers in the LAN just fine (via their local zeroconf domain). The only thing that does not work is reaching a server in the LAN via the public domain.

I assume that there is some problem moving from DNS to the local zeroconf network domains.

Comment: Does this work on other devices? This could just be a NAT hairpinning issue where the router does not expect incoming traffic when it happens at the exact same time as outgoing traffic and just ignores it.

Comment: @LPChip, I can resolve `myserver.example.org` on all devices in my network. But I can't resolve it inside docker containers.

Comment: Set up your own *iterative* resolver in your local network and it'll work. This is a good point to learn about the various DNS "servers": authoritative, iterative and recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fritzbox uses fritz.box as a local domain.

If you ask the resolver of your fritzbox you get this answer:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
myserver.fritz.box. 9   IN  NS  fritz.box.
```

Meaning the fritzbox considers itself in authoritiy of the .box domain.

But as we can see from the other resolver answers, if we really talk to a public DNS on the internet we get this response:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
box.            1641    IN  SOA ns0.centralnic.net. hostmaster.centralnic.net. 1688220651 900 1800 6048000 3600
```

That is because [.box](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) is a valid top level domain!

Using `# dig myserver.example.org` asks your local resolver. Usually nowadays the local resolver is `systemd-resolved` on recent linux.
It is a caching resolver, you can check this with `resolvectl statistics` and the cache can be emptied with `resolvectl flush-caches`.
A cached answer was my fist guess but it is actually works with an empty cache. That means it asks for `myserver.fritz.box` separately again after it encounters it, otherwise it would not resolve. It gets an answer because it asks the fritzbox for the .box domain.

As can be seen with `resolvectl status` there is a `DNS Domain: fritz.box` set. It probably got that setting via DHCP but it can be set manually by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` or on the commandline. See `man resolvectl` and `man systemd.network`. There is also [a setting for docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/). Usually that search domains setting means put that domain on blank hostnames that lack a domain part. Probably the `systemd-resolved` behaves in a special way for its configured search domains.

Using `dig @fritz.box myserver.example.org` ask the nameserver `@fritz.box` directly, bypassing the local cache and settings configured for the local OS resolver. Obviously the fritzbox DNS resolver only asks the DNS on the internet and does not resolve its local domains in a second step.

I come to this conclusion because the output of `@fritz.box` is the same as for example from `@1.1.1.1` or any other public DNS server.

As soon as real DNS servers are involved they try to resolve `myserver.fritz.box` in the public DNS and fail.

As there is no way to configure the DNS name of the fritzbox in the web interface the only two real solutions are:

- to file a bug report with AVM, they should use a non existing top
  level domain, `.local` is there for a reason
- or use another device for lan DNS that allows configuration of
  details.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I'd like to understand where exactly the local systemd resolver gets the correct IP from, and why the fritzbox resolver has no special handling for its own search domain. Still, I accepted your answer. You already helped immensely.

Comment: Curiously `.box` is a valid TLD but there's no real domains in it.  This TLD has been going through a consultation process for about 10 years at this time, source https://icannwiki.org/.box     So resolving `anything.box` to public DNS fails.   I would have guessed someone would have registered "fritz.box" for phishing/antiphishing purposes.

Comment: @SimonLenz This boils down to the question of who is responsible for doing the recursive queries. The nameserver usually is doing the recursions on behalf of the client and the client gets the final result. Obviously `systemd-resolved` acts like a recursive resolver due to the fact that it ask again although it got no result from public DNS. This is kind of a workaround that fixes the situation at hand. Why the fritzbox behaves the way it does and actually breaks the situation it created itself? That question we have to ask AVM.

Comment: To conclude the topic here:
As a workaround, I'm simply using now `myserver A <local IP in LAN>` instead of `myserver CNAME myserver.fritz.box`. This works for my case. Still, I'd prefer to use the CNAME approach from above.

Comment: @SimonLenz Be aware of [DNS rebinding attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding). The fritzbox itself has a whitelist for such hostnames with private IPs if you want to access its web gui. It checks the http header but does not filter DNS. A DNS server somewhere else could filter out private IPs, so your initial idea was better.